# Youtube Data API v3 get full watchHistory

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I have tried to dump watch history from YouTube, but playlistItems().list returns me only 163 last videos:

```
{u'etag': u'"F9iA7pnxqNgrkOutjQAa9F2k8HY/6lMoi7x7VY9xj1dR34GM6rOPfMM"',
 u'items': [],
 u'kind': u'youtube#playlistItemListResponse',
 u'pageInfo': {u'resultsPerPage': 50, u'totalResults': 163},
 u'prevPageToken': u'CJYBEAE'}
```

My http://www.youtube.com/feed/history contains much more than 163 videos.

I've tried to use pageToken param and paginate with it, but playlistItemListResponse was still limited by 163 items.

Is there any way to receive full history? Another way to paginate or something?

My best option for now is selenium-based script with user actions emulation. =)

I am using modifyed "Retrieve my uploads" example:

```py
# Auth here

youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
  http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

channels_response = youtube.channels().list(mine=True, part="contentDetails")\
    .execute()

for channel in channels_response["items"]:
    history_list_id = channel["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["watchHistory"]

    playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        playlistId=history_list_id,
        part="snippet",
        maxResults=50)

    while playlistitems_list_request:
        playlistitems_list_response = playlistitems_list_request.execute()

        for playlist_item in playlistitems_list_response["items"]:
            title = playlist_item["snippet"]["title"]
            video_id = playlist_item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]
            print "%s (%s)" % (title, video_id)

        playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
            playlistitems_list_request, playlistitems_list_response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that this some sort of behavior of this bug: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4642